# Как разрезать круг на четыре равные части?

Tags: css

Всем доброго времени суток как разрезать круг на четыре равные части в оригинале должно получиться так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Помогите пожалуйсто решить эту задачу**

```css
.cssload-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 49px;
    text-align: center;
}

.cssload-speeding-wheel {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 4px double;
    border-radius: 50%;
    
 
  
   border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
    
    animation: cssload-spin 575ms infinite linear;
        -o-animation: cssload-spin 575ms infinite linear;
        -ms-animation: cssload-spin 575ms infinite linear;
        -webkit-animation: cssload-spin 575ms infinite linear;
        -moz-animation: cssload-spin 575ms infinite linear;
}



@keyframes cssload-spin {
    100%{ transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-spin {
    100%{ -o-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-spin {
    100%{ -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-spin {
    100%{ -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-spin {
    100%{ -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="cssload-container">
<div class="cssload-speeding-wheel"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: по картинке вообще ничего не понятно. Что нужно сделать?

Comment: Данный круг имеет две вращающиеся линии а мне надо сделать четыре. То есть разрезать круг на четыре равные части

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно просто визуальное разделение, то пример ниже.
Если элементы круга нужны как отдельные блоки, то решение есть в [подобном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1168299/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-css-%D0%B8-js/1168475#1168475).

```css
.cssload-container {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cssload-speeding-wheel {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 4px double;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
}

.cssload-speeding-wheel:before,
.cssload-speeding-wheel:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 150%;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  left: calc(50% - 3px);
  top: -25%;
}

.cssload-speeding-wheel:after {
 transform: rotate(90deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="cssload-container">
<div class="cssload-speeding-wheel"></div>
</div>
```